# How Irvine set up to link his library in a project?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm, irvine32

Irvine give us the sample projects in his example zip files that work quite well. But he doesn't explain how to set up them in Visual Studio, especially the linking to Irvine32 or Irvine64. I tried to do that through online tutorials but it seems some steps are missing. In case of 32-bit project, the command windows never show up although the build is successful.  It does show up as expected when the sample project `Project32_VS2019` of Irvine is used.

From the tutorials online, I found that we need 3 steps to set up Irvine32 library in project's properties:

- Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories: c:\Irvine
- Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies: user32.lib, Irvine32.lib (the tutorials missed the user32.lib but it is in sample project)
- Microsoft Macro Assembler -> General -> Include Paths: c:\Irvine

Sample code to test:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data

.code
main PROC
     mov eax, 5
     writeint
     exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Have you configured your project to generate a console application rather than a windowed application?

Comment: great point, thanks @Michael, it works when i set it up as console app.